# java.util.HashMap / Neo4j multi-threaded hanging forever

Tags: java, multithreading, neo4j

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Neo4j version = `2.2.6`.

Two threads tried to access the same Node within the same milli, and iterate approx 500+ Relationships. The result is that both threads hang forever.

What might be the fix, or correct approach, please? (Apart from, "Don't do it twice.")

---

**Update:**

Using JStack to get a thread dump, it appears that it has nothing to with `neo4j` after all, but something to do with `HashSet` / `HashMap`. See update below ....

---

Log output - note the sequence of threads 1 & 2:

```
17:12:12.798 (neo4j-ro-pool-2) DEBUG [db.neo4j.Neo4jDao] - Open neo4j tx
17:12:12.798 (neo4j-ro-pool-2) DEBUG [db.neo4j.Neo4jDao] - Getting Node for [XYZ]
17:12:12.798 (neo4j-ro-pool-1) DEBUG [db.neo4j.Neo4jDao] - Open neo4j tx
17:12:12.798 (neo4j-ro-pool-1) DEBUG [db.neo4j.Neo4jDao] - Getting Node for [XYZ]
17:12:12.800 (neo4j-ro-pool-2) DEBUG [db.neo4j.Neo4jDao] - Got Node[284172852]
17:12:12.800 (neo4j-ro-pool-2) DEBUG [db.neo4j.Neo4jDao] - Getting Relationships for Node[284172852]
17:12:12.800 (neo4j-ro-pool-1) DEBUG [db.neo4j.Neo4jDao] - Got Node[284172852]
17:12:12.800 (neo4j-ro-pool-1) DEBUG [db.neo4j.Neo4jDao] - Getting Relationships for Node[284172852]
```

---

Code inside `Neo4jDao`:

```
public Data addNamesToData(Data data) {
    LOG.debug("Open neo4j tx");
    try (Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx()) {
        LOG.debug("Getting Node for [{}]", data);
        Node node = getNode(data);
        LOG.debug("Got {}", node);
        if (node == null) {
            LOG.debug("Existing Node for [{}] NOT FOUND", data);
            tx.success();
            return data;
        }
        addNames(node, data);
        tx.success();
        return data;
    } finally {
        LOG.debug("Close neo4j tx");
    }
}
```

---

```
private Data addNames(Node node, Data data) {
    LOG.debug("Getting Relationships for {}", node);
    Iterable<Relationship> rels = node.getRelationships(RelType.HAS_NAME_DATA, Direction.OUTGOING);
    int count = 0;
    for (Relationship rel : rels) { // Approx 500+ Relationships
        String name = NodeUtils.getNameFromNode(rel.getEndNode());
        LOG.trace("Adding Name [{}] to Data [{}]", name, data );
        data.addName(name);
        count++;
    }
    LOG.debug("Got {} Relationships for [{}]", count, node);
    return data;
}
```

---

**Data.addName():**

```
private final Set<String> nameSet = new HashSet<>();

public void addName(String name) {
    if(name != null) {
        this.nameSet.add(name);
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

Using JStack to get a thread dump, it appears that it has nothing to with `neo4j` after all, but something to do with `HashSet` / `HashMap`.

**Note:** The instance of `Data` is different on each thread ....

```
"neo4j-ro-pool-2" prio=10 tid=0x00007f572c002000 nid=0x6ebf runnable [0x00007f4eb40d8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:494)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
        at data.Data.addName(Data.java:162)
        at db.neo4j.Neo4jDao.addNames(Neo4jDao.java:231)
        at db.neo4j.Neo4jDao.addNamesToData(Neo4jDao.java:216)
        at bus.subscriber.NamesSubscriber.handle(NamesSubscriber.java:39)
        at bus.subscriber.NamesSubscriber.handle(NamesSubscriber.java:18)
        at bus.adaptor.SubscriberAdaptor$Task.run(SubscriberAdaptor.java:102)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00007f5845c439d8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"neo4j-ro-pool-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007f572c001000 nid=0x6ebe runnable [0x00007f4eb3cd4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:494)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
        at data.Data.addName(Data.java:162)
        at db.neo4j.Neo4jDao.addNames(Neo4jDao.java:231)
        at db.neo4j.Neo4jDao.addNamesToData(Neo4jDao.java:216)
        at bus.subscriber.NamesSubscriber.handle(NamesSubscriber.java:39)
        at bus.subscriber.NamesSubscriber.handle(NamesSubscriber.java:18)
        at bus.adaptor.SubscriberAdaptor$Task.run(SubscriberAdaptor.java:102)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00007f58494161d8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

---

Using a tip from [this blog](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/08/which-java-thread-consumes-my-cpu.html) I've identified which thread is chewing CPU.

```
$ top -n1 -H | grep -m1 java
28350 ubuntu    20   0 95.143g 0.013t 2.383g R 99.9 45.7   1154:16 java
$ printf "%x\n" 28350
6ebe
```

From the thread dump we see that `nid=0x6ebe` is thread `"neo4j-ro-pool-1"`. Not sure how this helps.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example (your code still has references to other functions) and provide a sample DB that shows this behaviour reproducible. So far the code looks ok to me, I wouldn't expect blocking here. Even if you run into deadlock, they should be detected and an appropriate exception should be thrown.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Thanks for your interest Stefan. A thread dump has shown this is possibly not a `neo4j` issue at all, as the threads are spinning inside `java.util.HashMap`

Comment: can you show `Data.addName(name)` function? Or maybe the whole class. And btw. do you get a Deadlock or infinit-loop?

Comment: @JohnnyAW I have added that code. It's basically null check + add String to a `java.util.HashSet`

Comment: Note, the instances of the `Data` object in each thread are different

Comment: @JohnnyAW Does not look like a Deadlock. Thread dump shows both threads as `RUNNABLE`

Comment: @Stewart yes, I don't see anything that could cause a deadlock. Can you try you code for small amount of Relationships? Can you show where do you call `addNamesToData()`?

Comment: @Stewart wait a second, is that the entire log, that you get? I mean is "Getting Relationships for Node[284172852]" the last entry, that you get for a Thread?

Comment: @JohnnyAW Yes, that is the last log entry for those 2 threads. Other threads are still doing their thing, but those 2 have been in this state for hours. `addNamesToData ()` is called from `NamesSubscriber` (see thread dump) which is basically just an interface to an event bus. The `Data` object gets shuttled around different events on the bus.

Comment: @Stewart hmm, but your Threads seems to reach `Data.addName`. What if you put log right after `node.getRelationships()` and at the beginning of the loop with relationship infos? You could try to disable the second Thread and see, if you get the same Problem.

Comment: @JohnnyAW Let's try this single-threaded then, with some more logging. That should help diagnosis. (Will take a random number of hours to reproduce, if it does.)

Comment: Make sure the event bus access is not synchronized so that the two threads are not locking each other out from progressing.